# HIVE trying to join and subtract one field from another select statement field

Tags: sql, hive

[image]

I am trying to join both of these select statements on id and playerID and year and yearID(schema below). Also subtract Aliases HAB - EG

```
  SELECT playerID, yearID, (E/ G) AS EG FROM fielding
  WHERE yearID > 2005 AND yearID < 2009 AND G > 20;


  SELECT id, year, (hits/ab) AS HAB FROM batting
  WHERE year > 2005 AND year < 2009 AND ab > 40;
```

JUST SCHEMA

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fielding
(playerID STRING ,yearID INT ,teamID STRING ,lgID STRING ,
POS STRING ,G INT ,GS INT , InnOuts INT , PO INT,A INT, E INT,  
DP INT , PB INT , WP INT ,SB INT ,CS INT , ZR INT ) ROW
FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LOCATION      '/home/hduser/hivetest/fielding';
```

JUST THE SCHEMA

```
 CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS batting(id STRING, year INT, team STRING,
 league STRING, games INT, ab INT, runs INT, hits INT, doubles INT, triples
 INT, homeruns INT, rbi INT, sb INT, cs INT, walks INT, strikeouts INT, ibb
 INT, hbp INT, sh INT, sf INT, gidp INT) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS
 TERMINATED BY ',' LOCATION '/home/hduser/hivetest/batting';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    a.playerID AS ID,
    a.yearID AS yearID,
    (b.HAB - a.EG) AS HAB-EG
FROM 
    (SELECT
        playerID,
        yearID,
        (E/G) AS EG
    FROM fielding
    WHERE (
            yearID > 2005
            AND yearID < 2009
            AND G > 20 
            )
    ) AS a
JOIN
    (SELECT
        id,
        year,
        (hits/ab) AS HAB
    FROM batting
    WHERE( 
            year > 2005
            AND year < 2009 
            AND ab > 40 
            )
    ) AS b ON a.playerID = b.id AND a.yearID = b.year;
```

Comment: just need to add back ticks to alias `HAB-EG` it should generate